# How to set a variable value in another class in Swift

Tags: ios, class, variables, swift, uiviewcontroller

How can I add a value to a variable in a class `myClass2` from another class `myClass` in swift?

I have already tried something like `myClass2().myvariable = "value"`, but this didn't work; my variable value is still `nil`. here's the code:

myViewController2:

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController2: UIViewController {

    var myVariable : String?;

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func showPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        display.text = myVariable;
    }

}
```

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let myClassInstance = myViewController2();
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func toView2Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        let view2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as myViewController2;
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view2, animated: true);
        myClassInstance.myVariable = "my new value";
    }

}
```

Comment: `var myVariable : String?;` shouldn't have a semicolon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating an instance of myViewController2 called myClass instance, but that's not the instance that you push onto the stack -- the instance being pushed is view2. So the last line in toView2Pressed should be,

```
view2.myVariable = "my new value"
```

You should delete the line, let myClassInstance = myViewController2(). It serves no purpose. You should also start your class names with a capital letter.